# How to require authentication to all views using social-auth-app-django? (All views are showing to non authenticated users)

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-middleware

I'm using social-auth-app-django version 3.1.0, and the login using Google OAuth2 is apparently running fine (I can succeed to login and get redirected back, also the user data from login is saved correctly (username, email))

But all my routes/views are accessible without authentication, even with the SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware (It was suposed to block this kind of unauthorized access I guess).

I just need all my current views (routes) to require authentication and redirect user to my login page.

This is my **settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_jinja',
    'bootstrapform_jinja',
    'django_celery_results',
    'social_django',
    'apps'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'wharf.auth.LoginRequiredMiddleware'
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'wharf.auth.SettingsBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
]

# Social Login Django
SOCIAL_AUTH_POSTGRES_JSONFIELD = True
SOCIAL_AUTH_URL_NAMESPACE = 'social'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = os.environ.get('SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY', '')
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = os.environ.get('SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET', '')
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_USE_UNIQUE_USER_ID = True

SOCIAL_AUTH_STRATEGY = 'social_django.strategy.DjangoStrategy'
SOCIAL_AUTH_STORAGE = 'social_django.models.DjangoStorage'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
LOGIN_URL = "/"
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS = ["webhook", "favicon.ico", "status"]

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.user_details',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'wharf.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django_jinja.backend.Jinja2',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            "match_extension": None,
            "app_dirname": "templates",
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `@login_required` from `django.contrib.auth.decorators` in every view